# "is" or "was," when we tell the time of something

Tags: past-simple, present-simple

Do we say "it is ×× years ago?"
If I'm trying to describe a cartoon, and there is a line that says "30 years ago" on one of pictures of this cartoon, should I say "it was 30 years ago" or "it is 30 years ago?"

Answer (score 2):

**Ago** generally takes the past tense, as you are looking back on the event.

> It was 30 years ago that something happened.

You can rephrase it using **since**, which takes the present tense and uses **now** as its perspective:

> It is (now) 30 years since something happened.

Narrators often use the historical present tense in these situations:

> **It is 30 years before my birth. My mother is a tiny baby. She knows nothing of what lies ahead**  ..... and so on.

You could frame a situation in which you might say **It is 30 years ago...** but it sounds clumsy to my ear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If you are describing an event in the past, you can say

> It was 30 years ago that it happened.

If you are speaking of the time since an event happened, you can say

> It has been 30 years since it happened.

or (less formally)

> It is 30 years since it happened.

If you are trying to describe a cartoon with a line of text that says
"Thirty years ago", you should quote what it says exactly, or just show the cartoon.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can describe a past even in the present tense plus the use of "since"; for example

> It is thirty years since I last visited New York.

This places the emphasis on the current time. "Had been" van be used in place of "is", which emphases the time interval more. Or you can write in the past tense:

> It was thirty years ago when i last visited New York.

This places the reader's attention more on the past event. It is possible to narrate past events in the present, as if the reader is seeing them through a time window or watching an old film or something. This is tricky to do well, and if not done well can be distracting to the reader. It is more likely in fiction or dramatized narrative.

> It is thirty years ago. I am entering the Empire State building in New York, on my way to meet with Roger Stone.

I would not advise using this technique unless the writer has practiced and knows how to do it effectively.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting! (And your spelling is interesting too XD. No offense!: ) Thank you for your explanation!